# Can I create a process with a pid of 8?

Tags: windows, system, pid

I wanted to create a process with a pid of 8.
(Just wondering if it's possible)

So I wrote and run the following code

```
...

while(1)
{
    CreateProcess(...);
    if(pi.dwProcessId < 100)
    {
        printf("%d ", pi.dwProcessId);
    }
    TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 0);
}
```

A process with a pid of around 80 was found.

But I can't even find a process with a pid below 50.

Q1. Can a process with pid 8 be created?

Q2. Could the pid of the system idle process is not 0?

Q3. Could the pid of the system process not be 4?

Q4. Are the pids of all the processes except system idle process and system process have non-fixed pid values?

Comment: Just wondering for what ? really pid 8 probably already busy by some process or thread. your forget about threads which also use pid (in system exist *PspCidTable* where stored id of process and threads). and must not hardcode 0, 4 etc but get this in run-time

Comment: I never thought about threads.
I checked with ProcessExplorer and the System process had most low number thread ids.
Can we think of pids or tids being assigned in the lowest possible number order?
And are system idle process and system process given the pids 0 and 4 simply because they were created first?

Comment: *Can we think of pids or tids being assigned in the lowest possible number order? And are system idle process and system process given the pids 0 and 4 simply because they were created first?* - yes. actually in my system i view thread with id=8 in *dwm.exe* process, but this is random